# Could any one help me on CSS input type and checked

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```css
#one input[type="checkbox"] + #Down{display:none;}

#one input[type="checkbox"]:checked + #Down{display:none;}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>
  <input name="one" type="checkbox" value="" class="inputCheck" id="one" /> 
      <div class="fl-L listItemsPadd">Sample</div>
      <a href="#" class="fl-L displayB helpIconlist-marg"></a>
      <label class="fl-L downloadPadd" id="Down"><a href="#" class="colorBL text-decoration ">Download</a>main form</label>
      <div class="clearboth"></div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I was trying to use `:checked` option in CSS. But because the label tag is not right beside the checkbox this is not working.

My main idea is to on check the "Downloadmain form" need to be displayed.

other wise it is not displayed.

Could any one please help. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve this by using the CSS `~` [general sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) like this:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gex312vo/)**

```css
input[type="checkbox"]#one ~ #Down {
    display:none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]#one:checked ~ #Down {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <input name="one" type="checkbox" value="" class="inputCheck" id="one" />
        <div class="fl-L listItemsPadd">Sample</div> <a href="#" class="fl-L displayB helpIconlist-marg"></a>
        <label class="fl-L downloadPadd" id="Down"><a href="#" class="colorBL text-decoration ">Download</a>main form</label>
        <div class="clearboth"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```